# I have issues with the path on the getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() function

Tags: flutter, path, getter

I get an error message over the path provider that says
error: The getter 'path' isn't defined for the class 'Future'.

I am trying to generate a PDF file following the https://pub.dev/packages/pdf#-example-tab- and this example https://github.com/javico2609/flutter-challenges/blob/master/lib/pages/code_examples/pdf_and_csv/pdf.dart

But as I go on I get the error that path isn't defined on the Future. But as I see on the web I am doing it right. Here is the code:

```
final String dir = (getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
final String path = '$dir/receta.pdf';
final File file = File(path);
file.writeAsBytesSync(newpdf.save());
```

As I said. I can't run the app because I get the message error: The getter 'path' isn't defined for the class 'Future'.

Also tried to write

```
final Future<Directory> directory = getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final String dir = directory.path;
final String path = '$dir/receta.pdf';
final File file = File(path);
file.writeAsBytesSync(newpdf.save());
```

But it doesn't work, path on the variable dir shows the error

Answer (score 6):

In `final Future<Directory> directory = getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();` `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` is any async function which means it will return the directory asynchronously , So then when you are trying to read `directory.path;`, `directory` is not initialized yet, its null.

Instead returning a future directory wait till it is initialized,

```
final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

Answer (score 1):

Import this.. it solves the issue

```
 import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put `await` keyword like this:

```dart
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final path = join(directory.path, 'db_todolist_sqflite');
```